# DataAnnotations multi-language - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using dataannotations with WPF, everything works perfect, what I want now is a multi language application. Create some resources **(.resx files - Language.resx, Language.en-US.resx, etc)**. The problem is that I always take the default **"Language.resx (es-AR)"** file. Try changing the application culture but it did not work. Some help? Thank you!

```
private string _firstName;
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global.Language), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredFiled")]
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set
    {
        if (_firstName != value)
        {
            _firstName = value;
            ValidateProperty(nameof(FirstName));
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Not work
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible typo? `ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredFiled"`

Comment: @DanWilson Thx! yes and no. Is a typo error but if the "ErrorMessageResourceName " don't exist, it does not compile.